# Time complexity of calculating $\log({x+1}) \bmod 2^N$

Tags: number-theory, algorithms, taylor-expansion, p-adic-number-theory

I want to know is it possible to calculate $\log({x+1}) \bmod 2^N$ faster than $O(N\sqrt{N}\log{N})$.

I'm only interested in the case that $x$ is integer and $x \bmod 4 = 0$.

### 1.Naive calculation $O(N^2\log{N})$

First of all, let's estimate the time complexity of naive calculation.
By Taylor expansion, $\log({x+1}) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{i}(-1)^{i+1}x^i$. The number of trainling zeros of $i$ is at most $\log_2(i)$. On the other hand, the number of trailing zeros (in 2-adic) of $x^i$ is $2i$ if $x \bmod 4=0$ and $x \bmod 8\neq 0$. So, if we calculate naively, we need to calculate up to around $N$ th term because higher order terms will become $0$ after taking mod $2^N$. Since the time complexity of multiplication of 2 n-bit integers is $O(n\log n)$, the time complexity of calculating $\log (x+1) \bmod 2^N$ is $O(\sum_{i=1}^{N} N\log{N})=O(N^2\log{N})$.

### 2. faster calculation $O(N\sqrt{N}\log{N})$

Now, there is an idea to speed up this calculation (I've heard this from maspy_stars-san). Using some integer $M, M'$, the relationship,$(1+2^nM)^2 \bmod 2^N=1+2^{n+1}M' \bmod 2^N$ holds from binomial theorem. Applying this relationship, we get following relationship.
\begin{align}
\log(x+1)&=\frac{\log\left((x+1)^{2^k}\right)}{2^k} \\
&=\frac{\log(1+2^{k+2}M'')}{2^k}
\end{align}
In this case, the number of trailing zeros of $i$ th term of $\log(1+x)$ s.t. $x=2^{k+2}M''$ is around $(k+2)i-\log_2i\approx (k+2)i$. So, we need to calculate up to $\frac{N+k}{k+2}$th term. Time complexity of $\log(x+1)$ in this case is $O\left(\sum_{i=1}^{\frac{N+k}{k+2}} (N+k) \log ({N+k})\right)=O\left(\frac{(N+k)^2}{k+2} \log (N+k)\right)$. On the other hand, time complexity of calculating $(x+1)^{2^k} \bmod 2^{N+k}$ is $O\left(k(N+k)\log(N+k)\right)$ by repetated squaring. By putting $k=N^\alpha$, $O\left(\frac{(N+k)^2}{k+2}\right)=O(N^{2-\alpha}+N+N^\alpha)$ and $O(k(N+k))=O(N^{\alpha+1}+N^{2\alpha})$. So, the optimal value of $k$ is $k=\sqrt{N}$ to reduce the time complexity. Now the total time complexity is $O(N\sqrt{N}\log{N})$.

### 3. My question

Is it possible to calculate $\log({x+1}) \bmod 2^N$ s.t. $x \bmod 4=0$ faster than $O(N\sqrt{N}\log{N})$?

Comment: $\log({x+1}) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{i}(-1)^{i+1}x^i$, no factorial in the denominator.  This changes the 2-adic order of many terms.  Also the series converges for all even $x$ but requires $x\equiv 1\bmod 4$ to make a bijective function.

Comment: I agree that Taylor expansion of $\log(1+x)$ of mine is wrong. I will fix it.

Comment: I believe Taylor expansion is fixed. I also agree that after fixing the denominator, $\log(1+x)$ will converge for all even $x$. Can I ask you to explain why we need $x=1\bmod 4$ to make a bijective function?

Comment: Try to compute $\log(-1)$.  The series thinks it's solving $2x=\log(1)=0$ thus in $2$-adics, proposes $x=0$.  So we get pairs of additive inverses having identical logarithms.  When we then calculate the exponentialdwe getvthe result that correspobds to $1+x\equiv 1\bmod 4$, like $+1$ instead of $-1$ or $-3$ instead of $+3$.  In my previous comment I mistyped $x\equiv 1$ but meant $1+x\equiv 1$.  In a hurry.